# How well do pressure measurements translate to temperatures?

Tags: experimental-physics, low-temperature-physics

At low temperatures we measured the changing pressure in a cryostat and converted these to temperatures using the function given by [Donnelly](https://www.nist.gov/sites/default/files/documents/srd/jpcrd551.pdf) ([p1267](https://www.nist.gov/sites/default/files/documents/srd/jpcrd551.pdf#page=51); [doi](http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.556028)). But it seems that this is only accurate if cooling is consistent. As in, if you're cooling helium by pumping on it, and you use the pressure to find the temperature then that's fine - but if you close a valve and the pressure goes up, when it starts to drop it no longer corresponds as closely to temperature. To what extent, if at all, is this true? And why does it happen? I've been unable to find any mention of this so it may be I misunderstood what our professor was saying.

Edit: equation used to convert pressure to temperature: $$T=\Sigma_{i=0}^{i=9} A_i \left( \frac{\ln P - B}{C} \right) $$

Comment: Please mention the function mentioned by Donnelly in your answer so that everyone needn't read the research paper to find out which one you are talking about.

Comment: @YashasSamaga Good point. I've referenced the page it's on, since it's a rather complicated function which is a sum of ten terms, with coefficients that require 6 decimal places of accuracy. Typing it into graphing software was fun.

Comment: You should write a summary of the research paper in your question so that everyone needn't download the paper and read it.

Comment: @YashasSamaga None of it is relevant barring that single page, it's just a collection of data tables on superfluid helium. Quantum turbulence, second sound properties, third sound, latent heat of vaporisation etc. And they don't derive the function; I believe that when they say ITS-90, they are referring to the equation in question, if that helps. I'll type up the form of the equation and leave out the coefficients.